# How does one sort a multi dimensional array by multiple columns in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've been working on this problem all day without a good solution.  Google has been little help as well.  I have a script that needs to accept a two dimensional array with an unknown number number of rows/columns.  The script also needs to accept a one dimensional array containing a list of columns to sort by, and another containing the order to sort by.  The call will look a little like this:

```
var orderList = {0,4,3,1};
var orderDir = {asc,desc,desc,asc};
dataArr = do2DArraySort(dataArr, orderList, orderDir);
```

The function do2DArraySort should return the dataArr array sorted by the first column (in ascending order), then by the fifth (in descending order), then by the third (in descending order), then by the second (in descending order).  I was able to make it two levels deep using the code below, but it fell apart once I tried adding a third sort column.  I understand why, but I can't figure out a good way to make it work.

Is there a standard way of doing this?  Could someone point me to a good script online I can study and use as a template?  Or can someone suggest a modification to my code to make it work?

Thanks!

```
//appends an array content to the original array
function addToArray(originalArray, addArray) {
    if (addArray.length != 0) {
        var curLength = 0;
        curLength = originalArray.length;
        var maxLength = 0;
        maxLength = curLength + addArray.length;  
        var itrerateArray = 0;
        for (var r = curLength; r < maxLength; r++) {   
            originalArray[r] = addArray[itrerateArray];
            itrerateArray++;
        }
    }
}

function do2DArraySort(arrayToBeSorted, sortColumnArray, sortDirectionArray) {
    if (arrayToBeSorted == "undefined" || arrayToBeSorted == "null") return arrayToBeSorted;
    if (arrayToBeSorted.length == 0) return arrayToBeSorted;
    if (sortColumnArray.length == 0) return arrayToBeSorted;
    tempArray = arrayToBeSorted; 
    var totalLength = sortColumnArray.length; 
    for(var m = 0; m < totalLength; m++) {
        if (m == 0) {   
            doBubbleSort(tempArray, tempArray.length, sortColumnArray[m], sortDirectionArray[m]);         
        } else {     
            doMultipleSort(tempArray, sortColumnArray[m], sortColumnArray[m-1], sortDirectionArray[m]);
        }
    } 
    return tempArray;
}

//check if a value exists in a single dimensional array
function checkIfExists(arrayToSearch, valueToSearch) {
    if (arrayToSearch == "undefined" || arrayToSearch == "null") return false;
    if (arrayToSearch.length == 0) return false;
    for (var k = 0; k < arrayToSearch.length; k++) {
        if (arrayToSearch[k] == valueToSearch) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//sorts an 2D array based on the distinct values of the previous column
function doMultipleSort(sortedArray, currentCol, prevCol, sortDirection) {
    var resultArray = new Array(); 
    var newdistinctValuesArray = new Array();
    //finding distinct previous column values 
    for (var n = 0; n < sortedArray.length; n++) {
        if (checkIfExists(newdistinctValuesArray, sortedArray[n][prevCol]) == false) newdistinctValuesArray.push(sortedArray[n][prevCol]);
    }
    var recCursor = 0;
    var newTempArray = new Array(); var toStoreArray = 0; 
    //for each of the distinct values
    for (var x = 0; x < newdistinctValuesArray.length; x++) {
        toStoreArray = 0;
        newTempArray = new Array();  
        //find the rows with the same previous column value
        for (var y = 0; y < sortedArray.length; y++) {
            if (sortedArray[y][prevCol] == newdistinctValuesArray[x]) {
                newTempArray[toStoreArray] = sortedArray[y];
                toStoreArray++;
            }
        }       //sort the row based on the current column
        doBubbleSort(newTempArray, newTempArray.length, currentCol, sortDirection);
        //append it to the result array
        addToArray(resultArray, newTempArray);
    }
    tempArray = resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The array literal `[]` is preferred over `new Array`. The notation `{0,4,3,1}` is not valid and should be `[0,4,3,1]`.

Is there a need for reinventing the wheel? Two arrays can be joined using:

```
originalArray = originalArray.concat(addArray);
```

Elements can be appended to the end using:

```
array.push(element);
```

Arrays have a method for sorting the array. By default, it's sorted numerically:

```
// sort elements numerically
var array = [1, 3, 2];
array.sort(); // array becomes [1, 2, 3]
```

Arrays can be reversed as well. Continuing the previous example:

```
array = array.reverse(); //yields [3, 2, 1]
```

To provide custom sorting, you can pass the optional function argument to `array.sort()`:

```
array = [];
array[0] = [1, "first element"];
array[1] = [3, "second element"];
array[2] = [2, "third element"];
array.sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    return element_a[0] - element_b[0];
});
/** array becomes (in order):
 * [1, "first element"]
 * [2, "third element"]
 * [3, "second element"]
 */
```

Elements will retain their position if the element equals an other element. Using this, you can combine multiple sorting algoritms. You must apply your sorting preferences in reverse order since the last sort has priority over previous ones. To sort the below array by the first column (descending order) and then the second column (ascending order):

```
array = [];
array.push([1, 2, 4]);
array.push([1, 3, 3]);
array.push([2, 1, 3]);
array.push([1, 2, 3]);
// sort on second column
array.sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    return element_a[1] - element_b[1];
});
// sort on first column, reverse sort
array.sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    return element_b[0] - element_a[0];
});
/** result (note, 3rd column is not sorted, so the order of row 2+3 is preserved)
 * [2, 1, 3]
 * [1, 2, 4] (row 2)
 * [1, 2, 3] (row 3)
 * [1, 3, 3]
 */
```

To sort latin strings (i.e. English, German, Dutch), use `String.localeCompare`:

```
array.sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    return element_a.localeCompare(element_b);
});
```

To sort date's from the `Date` object, use their milliseconds representation:

```
array.sort(function (element_a, element_b) {
    return element_a.getTime() - element_b.getTime();
});
```

You could apply this sort function to all kind of data, just follow the rules:

`x` is the result from comparing two values which should be returned by a function passed to `array.sort`.

1. `x < 0`: `element_a` should come before `element_b`
2. `x = 0`: `element_a` and `element_b` are equal, the elements are not swapped
3. `x > 0`: `element_a` should come after `element_b`

Comment: Thank you; this is fantastic and very enlightening.  I'm going to do some further research now.  It looks like this works great assuming all elements are numeric, but as my array could contain a mix of numbers, dates, characters, etc, I will need to figure out how to modify the function within the sort to determine field type and sort accordingly.  Do you happen to know a good resource you could point me to for this?

Comment: @Nicholas: I included an example for sorting dates of the `Date` object and strings. If you understand the use of arrays and know a bit Javascript, you can sort everything providing you've the requirements for the sorting algorithm. Should it be unclear, add a comment it can be explained.

Comment: Lekensteyn; again thank you.  I think I understand well enough (to be dangerous) now ;).  I've found that the basic sorting algorithm appears to work fine on dates without having to use the getTime method.  Am I missing any pitfalls in skipping that?  You're a true life saver.  :)

Comment: @Nicholas: if your "date" is a string, you need to convert it to a date first: `(new Date("Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200")).getTime()`. For large arrays, it might be preferred to cache the result, and use that cached result for comparison.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer but there is one catch: Lekensteyn states about the Array.prototype.sort() method that "Elements will retain their position if the element equals an other element", however the ECMAScript spec explicitly says that implementations do NOT have to do this, and some browsers do not. Chrome doesn't, and Opera doesn't. Hence, you can NOT expect several subsequent calls to sort() to behave the way you expect across browsers.

Answer (score 4):

```
var arr = [27, 2, 4, 13]
arr.sort();
```

sets arr as [13, 2, 27, 4], because arrays are sorted as strings by default in JavaScript

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

sets arr as [2, 4, 13, 27] sorting numerically forward.

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
});
```

sets arr as [27, 13, 4, 2] sorting numerically in reverse.

```
var marr = [[]];
marr.shift();

marr.push(["frog", 4, 27, 13]);
marr.push(["frog", 11, 5, 12]);
marr.push(["cat", 16, 3, 5]);
marr.push(["dog", 11, 7, 21]);
marr.push(["cat", 16, 21, 6]);
marr.push(["dog", 10, 280, 5]);
marr.push(["dog", 10, 32, 5]);

marr.sort();
```

sets marr as follows, sorting array rows, by column in order as strings..

```
["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["cat", 16, 3, 5]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]
["frog", 4, 27, 13]
```

calling sort by column allows sorting by a single column.
sort row by 3rd column as number..

```
marr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[2] - b[2];
});

["cat", 16, 3, 5]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]
["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["frog", 4, 27, 13]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
```

then sort 4th column in reverse as number..

```
marr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[3] - a[3];
});

["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["frog", 4, 27, 13]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]
["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["cat", 16, 3, 5]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
```

then sort 2nd column ascending as number

```
marr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});

["frog", 4, 27, 13]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]
["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["cat", 16, 3, 5]
```

notice each time you sort, prior order is maintained where new column is a match to a consecutive row.

Now you can roll in alpha sorting of the first column

```
// asc
marr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
});

["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["cat", 16, 3, 5]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["frog", 4, 27, 13]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]

// desc
marr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a[0] > b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
});

["frog", 4, 27, 13]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["cat", 16, 3, 5]
```

sort all the numeric columns in a desc loop : 4, 3, 2
then sort the 1st column asc as string

```
for (var colid = 3; colid > 0; colid--) {
    marr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (b[colid] - a[colid]);
    });
}

// 1st row as string asc
marr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
});

["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["cat", 16, 3, 5]
["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]
["frog", 4, 27, 13]
```

combine these sorts.. in a more logical way, in order of what column you want to sort & how you want it sorted first

```
// c1 asc, c2 desc, c3 asc, c4 asc
marr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : (a[0] == b[0]) ?
        (b[1] - a[1]) || (a[2] - b[2]) || (a[3] - b[3]) : 1;
});

["cat", 16, 3, 5]
["cat", 16, 21, 6]
["dog", 11, 7, 21]
["dog", 10, 32, 5]
["dog", 10, 280, 5]
["frog", 11, 5, 12]
["frog", 4, 27, 13]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are already good answers to this question, would like to add a short functions to handle multiple key array sort inspired solution of https://stackoverflow.com/users/2279116/shinobi.

```
// sort function handle for multiple keys
const sortCols  = (a, b, attrs) => Object.keys(attrs)
    .reduce((diff, k) =>  diff == 0 ? attrs[k](a[k], b[k]) : diff, 0);
```

Let's take an following example

```
const array = [
    [1, 'hello', 4],
    [1, 'how', 3],
    [2, 'are', 3],
    [1, 'hello', 1],
    [1, 'hello', 3]
];

array.sort((a, b) => sortCols(a, b, { 
   0: (a, b) => a - b, 
   1: (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b), 
   2: (a, b) => b - a
}))
```

The output would be following.

```
[ 1, "hello", 4 ]​
[ 1, "hello", 3 ]​
[ 1, "hello", 1 ]​
[ 1, "how", 3 ]
​[ 2, "are", 3 ]
```

Comment: this doesn't work if, say you want to sort the 2nd column THEN the 1st column. It will always start sorting columns from left to right because Object.keys() return the keys in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a higher-order function which takes the orderList and orderDir as arguments and returns a comparator function which can be passed directly to Array#sort.  This way you can try different implementations (which trade off simplicity for performance, for example).

This untested code demonstrates the idea:

```
var getComparator = function(orderList, orderDir) {
  var len = orderList.length; // XXX: assume == orderDir.length
  return function(a, b) {
    var cmp, ax, bx, i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) { # For each field and direction...
      ax = a[orderList[i]];
      bx = b[orderList[i]];
      cmp = ax.localeCompare(bx); # compare elements...
      if (cmp != 0) { # if not equal then indicate order...
        return (orderDir[i]=='asc') ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
    return 0; # otherwise, indicate equality.
  };
};
dataArr.sort(getComparator(orderList, orderDir));
```

Note that you'll want to be careful about using "localeCompare" vs subtraction for strings vs numbers, so perhaps that aspect could be parameterized to the getComparator function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lekensteyn's excellent response, I've developed the following solution to my needs.  I haven't done full QA testing on it yet and don't know if it is perfect (in fact, I'm quite sure it's not), but I hope that others can get some use out of this and build upon it for their needs.  I'll post an update if any major changes needed made.

```
function do2DArraySort(dataArr, orderList, orderDir) {
    for (x=orderList.length-1; x >= 0; x--) {
        if (orderDir[x] == 'asc') {
            dataArr.sort(sortMethodFunctionAsc);
        } else {
            dataArr.sort(sortMethodFunctionDesc);
        }
    }

    return dataArr;
}

function sortMethodFunctionAsc(a, b) {
    if ((IsNumeric(a[orderList[x]]) && IsNumeric(b[orderList[x]])) || (IsDate(a[orderList[x]]) && IsDate(b[orderList[x]]))) {
        return a[orderList[x]] - b[orderList[x]];
    } else {
        if (a[orderList[x]].toString() > b[orderList[x]].toString()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a[orderList[x]].toString() < b[orderList[x]].toString()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

function sortMethodFunctionDesc(a, b) {
    if ((IsNumeric(a[orderList[x]]) && IsNumeric(b[orderList[x]])) || (IsDate(a[orderList[x]]) && IsDate(b[orderList[x]]))) {
        return b[orderList[x]] - a[orderList[x]];
    } else {
        if (a[orderList[x]].toString() < b[orderList[x]].toString()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a[orderList[x]].toString() > b[orderList[x]].toString()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}


function IsNumeric(input) {
    return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
}

function IsDate(testValue) {
    var returnValue = false;
    var testDate;
    try {
        testDate = new Date(testValue);
        if (!isNaN(testDate)) {
            returnValue = true;
        } else {
            returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        returnValue = false;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```