# sort Javascript array by two numeric fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
grouperArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aSize = a.gsize;
    var bSize = b.gsize;
    var aLow = a.glow;
    var bLow = b.glow;
    console.log(aLow + " | " + bLow);      
    return (aSize < bSize) ? -1 : (aSize > bSize) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

This code sorts the array by `gsize`, smallest to largest.

How would I change it to sort first by `gsize` and then by `glow`?

Comment: sort function reacts on positive, negative or zero result. so you can just write: "return aSize - bSize". it will be more simple and readable code.

Comment: Top [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24292023/8112776), compressed: **Sort array of objects by `col0` then `col1` (ascending):** `myArray.sort(function(a,b){return a.col0-b.col0||a.col1-b.col1});`  Alternate example: **Sort array of arrays by index #0, then #2, then #1 (descending):** `myArray.sort(function(a,b){return b[0]-a[0]||b[2]-a[2]||b[1]-a[1]});`

Comment: Covered by the more general "[How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6913512/90527)"

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
grouperArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aSize = a.gsize;
    var bSize = b.gsize;
    var aLow = a.glow;
    var bLow = b.glow;
    console.log(aLow + " | " + bLow);

    if(aSize == bSize)
    {
        return (aLow < bLow) ? -1 : (aLow > bLow) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (aSize < bSize) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: To make this more concise using arrow syntax, without resorting to non-obvious techniques shown in some other answers: `grouperArray.sort((a, b) => a.gsize == b.gsize ? a.glow - b.glow : a.gsize - b.gsize`. To make the code easier to understand, we keep explicit the test for `==`.

Answer (score 246):

```
grouperArray.sort(function (a, b) {   
    return a.gsize - b.gsize || a.glow - b.glow;
});
```

shorter version

Comment: great short cut! helped me put a more complex solution together.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101475/how-does-one-sort-a-multi-dimensional-array-by-multiple-columns-in-javascript/56982102#56982102

Comment: Nice and clean! The only thing it only works for numbers.

Comment: Can you explain the logic in here ?!. It worked for me to `sort an array with a key's value first` and then `sort the result with another key's value `

Comment: @KTM The logic goes as follow: if both gsize are equal, then the first part of the condition is equal to 0, which is considered as false, and the second part of the condition is executed.

Comment: @Scalpweb Yeah :) so this works to sort an array with any number of keys one by one right?! Nice trick

Comment: if you want to understand why that works you might wanna look at 
https://medium.com/@safareli/pss-ordering-is-a-monoid-61a4029387e

Answer (score 57):

```
grouperArray.sort((a, b) => a.gsize - b.gsize || a.glow - b.glow);
```

Even shorter version using arrow syntax!

Comment: Even shorter, take out the spaces: `grouperArray.sort((a,b)=>a.gsize-b.gsize||a.glow-b.glow);`

Comment: if you want to understand why that works you might wanna look at 
https://medium.com/@safareli/pss-ordering-is-a-monoid-61a4029387e

Answer (score 16):

I realize this was asked some time ago, but I thought I would add my solution.

This function generates sort methods dynamically. simply supply each sortable child property name, prepended with +/- to indicate ascending or descending order.  Super re-usable, and it doesn't need to know anything about the data structure you've put together.  Could be made idiot proof - but doesn't seem necessary.

```
function getSortMethod(){
    var _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function(a, b){
        for(var x in _args){
            var ax = a[_args[x].substring(1)];
            var bx = b[_args[x].substring(1)];
            var cx;

            ax = typeof ax == "string" ? ax.toLowerCase() : ax / 1;
            bx = typeof bx == "string" ? bx.toLowerCase() : bx / 1;

            if(_args[x].substring(0,1) == "-"){cx = ax; ax = bx; bx = cx;}
            if(ax != bx){return ax < bx ? -1 : 1;}
        }
    }
}
```

example usage:

items.sort(getSortMethod('-price', '+priority', '+name'));

this would sort `items` with lowest `price` first, with ties going to the item with the highest `priority`.  further ties are broken by the item `name`

where items is an array like:

```
var items = [
    { name: "z - test item", price: "99.99", priority: 0, reviews: 309, rating: 2 },
    { name: "z - test item", price: "1.99", priority: 0, reviews: 11, rating: 0.5 },
    { name: "y - test item", price: "99.99", priority: 1, reviews: 99, rating: 1 },
    { name: "y - test item", price: "0", priority: 1, reviews: 394, rating: 3.5 },
    { name: "x - test item", price: "0", priority: 2, reviews: 249, rating: 0.5 } ...
];
```

live demo:  http://gregtaff.com/misc/multi_field_sort/

EDIT:  Fixed issue with Chrome.

Comment: for typescript (for not getting an `error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got ..`) use the syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116634/5287221

Answer (score 7):

I expect the [ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) operator `((aSize < bSize) ? -1 : (aSize > bSize) ? 1 : 0;)` has you confused.  You should check out the link to understand it better.

Until then, here's your code blown out into full if/else.

```
grouperArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.gsize < b.gsize)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (a.gsize > b.gsize)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (a.glow < b.glow)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a.glow > b.glow)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's an implementation for those who may want something more generic that would work with any number of fields.

```
Array.prototype.sortBy = function (propertyName, sortDirection) {

    var sortArguments = arguments;
    this.sort(function (objA, objB) {

        var result = 0;
        for (var argIndex = 0; argIndex < sortArguments.length && result === 0; argIndex += 2) {

            var propertyName = sortArguments[argIndex];
            result = (objA[propertyName] < objB[propertyName]) ? -1 : (objA[propertyName] > objB[propertyName]) ? 1 : 0;

            //Reverse if sort order is false (DESC)
            result *= !sortArguments[argIndex + 1] ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return result;
    });

}
```

Basically, you may specify any number of property name / sort direction:

```
var arr = [{
  LastName: "Doe",
  FirstName: "John",
  Age: 28
}, {
  LastName: "Doe",
  FirstName: "Jane",
  Age: 28
}, {
  LastName: "Foo",
  FirstName: "John",
  Age: 30
}];

arr.sortBy("LastName", true, "FirstName", true, "Age", false);
//Will return Jane Doe / John Doe / John Foo

arr.sortBy("Age", false, "LastName", true, "FirstName", false);
//Will return John Foo / John Doe / Jane Doe
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grouperArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  var aSize = a.gsize;
  var bSize = b.gsize;
  var aLow = a.glow;
  var bLow = b.glow;
  console.log(aLow + " | " + bLow);      
  return (aSize < bSize) ? -1 : (aSize > bSize) ? 1 : ( (aLow < bLow ) ? -1 : (aLow > bLow ) ? 1 : 0 );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
grouperArray.sort(function (a, b) {
     var aSize = a.gsize;     
     var bSize = b.gsize;     
     var aLow = a.glow;
     var bLow = b.glow;
     console.log(aLow + " | " + bLow);
     return (aSize < bSize) ? -1 : (aSize > bSize) ? 1 : (aLow < bLow) ? -1 : (aLow > bLow) ? 1 : 0); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation that uses recursion to sort by any number of sort fields from 1 to infinite.  You pass it a results array which is an array of result objects to sort, and a sorts array which is an array of sort objects defining the sort.  Each sort object must have a "select" key for the key name that it sorts by and an "order" key which is a string indicating "ascending" or "descending".

```
sortMultiCompare = (a, b, sorts) => {
    let select = sorts[0].select
    let order = sorts[0].order
    if (a[select] < b[select]) {
        return order == 'ascending' ? -1 : 1
    } 
    if (a[select] > b[select]) {
        return order == 'ascending' ? 1 : -1
    }
    if(sorts.length > 1) {
        let remainingSorts = sorts.slice(1)
        return this.sortMultiCompare(a, b, remainingSorts)
    }
    return 0
}

sortResults = (results, sorts) => {
    return results.sort((a, b) => {
        return this.sortMultiCompare(a, b, sorts)
    })
}

// example inputs
const results = [
    {
        "LastName": "Doe",
        "FirstName": "John",
        "MiddleName": "Bill"
    },
    {
        "LastName": "Doe",
        "FirstName": "Jane",
        "MiddleName": "Bill"
    },
    {
        "LastName": "Johnson",
        "FirstName": "Kevin",
        "MiddleName": "Bill"
    }
]

const sorts = [
    {
        "select": "LastName",
        "order": "ascending"
    },
    {
        "select": "FirstName",
        "order": "ascending"
    },
    {
        "select": "MiddleName",
        "order": "ascending"
    }    
]

// call the function like this:
let sortedResults = sortResults(results, sorts)
```

Answer (score 3):

**A dynamic way to do that with MULTIPLE keys:**

- filter unique values from each col/key of sort
- put in order or reverse it
- add weights width zeropad for each object based on indexOf(value) keys values
- sort using caclutated weights

[image]

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'orderBy', {
value: function(sorts) { 
    sorts.map(sort => {            
        sort.uniques = Array.from(
            new Set(this.map(obj => obj[sort.key]))
        );

        sort.uniques = sort.uniques.sort((a, b) => {
            if (typeof a == 'string') {
                return sort.inverse ? b.localeCompare(a) : a.localeCompare(b);
            }
            else if (typeof a == 'number') {
                return sort.inverse ? (a < b) : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
            }
            else if (typeof a == 'boolean') {
                let x = sort.inverse ? (a === b) ? 0 : a? -1 : 1 : (a === b) ? 0 : a? 1 : -1;
                return x;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    });

    const weightOfObject = (obj) => {
        let weight = "";
        sorts.map(sort => {
            let zeropad = `${sort.uniques.length}`.length;
            weight += sort.uniques.indexOf(obj[sort.key]).toString().padStart(zeropad, '0');
        });
        //obj.weight = weight; // if you need to see weights
        return weight;
    }

    this.sort((a, b) => {
        return weightOfObject(a).localeCompare( weightOfObject(b) );
    });

    return this;
}
});
```

**Use:**

```
// works with string, number and boolean
let sortered = your_array.orderBy([
    {key: "type", inverse: false}, 
    {key: "title", inverse: false},
    {key: "spot", inverse: false},
    {key: "internal", inverse: true}
]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use

```
function sort(a, b) {
    var _a = "".concat(a.size, a.glow);
    var _b = "".concat(b.size, b.glow);
    return _a < _b;
}
```

concat the two items as a string and they will be sorted by a string value. If you want you could wrap _a and _b with parseInt to compare them as numbers if you know they will be numerical.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for the case, when you have a priority sort key, which might not exist in some particular items, so you have to sort by fallback keys.

An input data example (**id2** is priority sort key):

```js
const arr = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2, id2: 3},
    {id: 4},
    {id: 3},
    {id: 10, id2: 2},
    {id: 7},
    {id: 6, id2: 1},
    {id: 5},
    {id: 9, id2: 2},
    {id: 8},
];
```

And the output should be:

```
[ { id: 6, id2: 1 },
  { id: 9, id2: 2 },
  { id: 10, id2: 2 },
  { id: 2, id2: 3 },
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 },
  { id: 5 },
  { id: 7 },
  { id: 8 } ]
```

The comparator function will be like:

```js
arr.sort((a,b) => {
  if(a.id2 || b.id2) {
    if(a.id2 && b.id2) {
      if(a.id2 === b.id2) {
        return a.id - b.id;
      }
      return a.id2 - b.id2;
    }
    return a.id2 ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return a.id - b.id
});
```

*P.S. In case if **.id** of **.id2** can be zeros, consider to use `typeof`.*

Answer (score 1):

**Let's simplify.**

Say you have an array of arrays:

```
let tmp = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [0, 2],
    [2, 2],
    [1, 2],
]
```

Executing:

```
tmp.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[1] != b[1])
        return a[1] - b[1];
    else
        return a[0] - b[0];
})
```

Will yield:

```
[
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 1],
    [0, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = [
    { name: "z - test item", price: "99.99", priority: 0, reviews: 309, rating: 2 },
    { name: "z - test item", price: "1.99", priority: 0, reviews: 11, rating: 0.5 },
    { name: "y - test item", price: "99.99", priority: 1, reviews: 99, rating: 1 },
    { name: "y - test item", price: "0", priority: 1, reviews: 394, rating: 3.5 },
    { name: "x - test item", price: "0", priority: 2, reviews: 249, rating: 0.5 }];

items.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); 
    var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();   
    var nameC = a.price.toUpperCase(); 
    var nameD = b.price.toUpperCase(); 

    if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB || nameC > nameD) {
            return 1;
        }

        // names must be equal
        return 0;
    });`
```

Comment: Hi @aafridah . Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider adding a little bit of description while submitting a code snippet. Try to describe what your code does and how exactly will it solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
grouperArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aSize = a.gsize;
    var bSize = b.gsize;
    if (aSize !== aSize)
        return aSize - bSize;
    return a.glow - b.glow;
});
```

not tested, but I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
grouperArray.sort(
  function(a,b){return a.gsize == b.gsize ? a.glow - b.glow : a.gsize - b.gsize}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i sort notification list by param 'important' and by 'date'

- step 1: i filter notifications by 'important' and unImportant

  ```
  let importantNotifications = notifications.filter(
          (notification) => notification.isImportant);

    let unImportantNotifications = notifications.filter(
          (notification) => !notification.isImportant);
  ```
- step 2: i sort them by date

  ```
    sortByDate = (notifications) => {
    return notifications.sort((notificationOne, notificationTwo) => {
      return notificationOne.date - notificationTwo.date;
    });
  };
  ```
- step 3: merge them

  ```
  [
      ...this.sortByDate(importantNotifications),
      ...this.sortByDate(unImportantNotifications),
    ];
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to use the new [tidy.js package](https://pbeshai.github.io/tidy/) you can achieve this with

```
tidy(input_array,
  arrange(['var1', desc('var2')])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other answers here I got inconsistent data on my arrays where 1 wanted a primary ASC sort on field x and a secondary DESC sort on field y.
The solution is in giving the primary sort more importance by multiplying the number with lets say 1000000000

```
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => {
    return (
        // Multiply by a high number to the most important sort, that makes them heavier than the second sort

        // First sort ASC (notice the - minus in the end instead of the || in other answers !)
        (a.paramX * 1000000000) -
        (b.paramX * 1000000000) -

        // Second sort DESC (switch them if you want ASC too)
        (a.paramY - b.paramY)
    )
})
```

for sorting on multiple dates on the object it is this:

```
// param date1 ASC and param date2 DESC
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => {
    return (
        (a.date1.getTime() * 1000000000) -
        (b.date1.getTime() * 1000000000) -
        (a.date2.getTime() - b.date2.getTime())
    )
})
```