# javascript sort array double sort

Tags: javascript

I have an array `MyArrayOfItems` of `Item` objects with objects that look like this:

```
Item
{
  ContainerID: i, // int
  ContainerName: 'SomeName', // string
  ItemID: j, // int
  ItemName: 'SomeOtherName' // string
}
```

I want to sort this array so that it's sorted by `ContainerID` and then by `ItemName` alphabetically.

I have a custom sort function that so far looks like this:

```
function CustomSort(a, b) {

  Item1 = a['ContainerID'];
  Item2 = b['ContainerID'];

  return Item1 - Item2;
}

MyArrayOfItems.sort(CustomSort);
```

This sorts by ContainerID but how do I then sort by ItemName?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript sort array by two fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129952/javascript-sort-array-by-two-fields)

Comment: @FelixKling: not really; I need it to sort alphabetically.

Comment: So? You can easily compare stings with `<` and `>` though I agree that `localCompare` is a better way. I thought the overall question was about how to sort by two properties, in which case it is clearly a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function. And use it when `ContainerID` of `a` and `b` are equal.

```
function CustomSort(a, b) {
  var Item1 = a['ContainerID'];
  var Item2 = b['ContainerID'];
  if(Item1 != Item2){
      return (Item1 - Item2);
  }
  else{
      return (a.ItemName.localeCompare(b.ItemName));
  }
}
```

To tweak the sorting order you can always put `-` in front of any `return` expression.

Comment: It should. As its in JavaScript 1.2 which is very old.

Comment: localcompare is a good choice, but as I remember chrome had issues with it..http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=459

Comment: `Item1 - Item2 !=0` can be simplified to `Item1 != Item2`.

Comment: ok, thanks Felix; I put Item1 !== Item2 to use the triple comparator.

Answer (score 5):

```
function CustomSort(a, b) {

  Item1 = a['ContainerID'];
  Item2 = b['ContainerID'];
  if(Item1 - Item2 !=0){
      return Item1 - Item2;
  }
  else{
      if (a.ItemName < b.ItemName)
         return -1;
      if (a.ItemName > b.ItemName)
         return 1;
      return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks; upvoted because it also works. I prefer localeCompare though.

Answer (score 0):

A nice simplification of this is:

```js
function CustomSort(a, b) {
  var Item1 = a['ContainerID'];
  var Item2 = b['ContainerID'];
  

 if(Item1 != Item2){
      return (Item1 - Item2);
  }
  else{
      return (a.ItemName.localeCompare(b.ItemName));
  }
}
```