# sort strings by string elements

Tags: javascript

Need help for below scenario

000-2022, 000-2023, 005-2021, 000-2021, 003-2021, 004-2022, 007-2021

last 4 digits are year and middle 3 digits are priority number. I need this to be sorted with highest year first and below it should come the corresponding priority number of that years and then it should move on to the next lesser year.

expected result :

000-2023, 000-2022, 004-2022, 000-2021, 003-2021, 005-2021, 007-2021

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you tell us what you have tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: What did you try so far? If you are lazy to google, please be informed this post will be flagged.

Comment: I am not sure of the logic for this. So not able to start

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript/ see this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript sort array double sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403797/javascript-sort-array-double-sort)

Answer (score 1):

this way

```js
let arr = ['000-2022', '000-2023', '005-2021', '000-2021', '003-2021', '004-2022', '007-2021']

arr.sort( (a,b)=>
  {
  let [aN,aY] = a.split('-').map(Number)
    , [bN,bY] = b.split('-').map(Number)
  return aY - bY || aN - bN  
  })

console.log(  arr )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Comment: Сondition check is rock!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function for sorting. And use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function to split the string.

```js
let arr = ["000-2022", "000-2023", "005-2021", "000-2021", "003-2021", "004-2022", "007-2021"]
arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  let [aPriority,aYear] = a.split("-").map(it => Number(it));
  let [bPriority,bYear] = b.split("-").map(it => Number(it));
  return bYear > aYear ? 1 : 
         aYear > bYear ? -1 : 
         (aPriority - bPriority);
  
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend sanitising the input data first into a structured format. Then the sorting code will be much easier to understand.

Here's an example:

```js
a = ["000-2022", "000-2023", "005-2021", "000-2021", "003-2021", "004-2022", "007-2021"]
structured = a.map((e) => {
  [priority, year] = e.split("-")
  return {priority, year}
})

// `sort()` changes the array in place, so there's no need for a new var
structured.sort((e1, e2) => {
  if (e1.year !== e2.year) {
    // year is different, so sort by that first
    return e1.year < e2.year && 1 || -1
  } else {
    // if year is the same, sort by priority
    return e1.priority < e2.priority && 1 || -1
  }
})
console.log(structured)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ordinary sort function

```js
const data = ['000-2022', '000-2023', '005-2021', '000-2021', '003-2021', '004-2022', '007-2021']

const result = data.sort((item1, item2)=> {
  const [prior1, year1] = item1.split('-').map(Number);
  const [prior2, year2] = item2.split('-').map(Number);
  const yearRes = year2 - year1;
  
  return (yearRes === 0) 
    ? prior1 - prior2
    : yearRes  
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```