# Sort an array first by boolean column then by string column

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, typescript

I'm trying to so sort an array by 2 fields. I have a boolean: isFavorite and a string: name.
All the booleans who are true have to be the first items. But I want the array to be alphabetic. This is my code so far (tried multiple things):

```
data.sort(function (x,y) {
    if (x.isFavorite){
        return -1;
    }
    if (x.isFavorite && !y.isFavorite && (x.name < y.name)){
        return -1;
    }  else if ((x.isFavorite === y.isFavorite) && (x.name === y.name)){
        return 0;
    } else if (x.isFavorite && y.isFavorite && (x.name < y.name)){
        return -1;
    } else if (!x.isFavorite && !y.isFavorite && (x.name > y.name)){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript sort array by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129952/javascript-sort-array-by-two-fields)

Answer (score 14):

Why so much conditions and overlapping ?

Just use `logical OR` operator in order to **sort** array by two fields.

Also, I used `+ (Boolean)` in order to force converting to **Number**.

```
grouperArray.sort((a, b) => (+a.isFavorite) - (+b.isFavorite) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
```

```js
let data = [{ isFavorite:false, name:'A' }, { isFavorite:true, name:'C' }, { isFavorite:true, name:'B' }];
data.sort((a,b) => (+b.isFavorite) - (+a.isFavorite) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const data = [
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'b'},
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'f'},
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'c'},
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'a'},
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'd'},
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'g'}
];

const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.isFavorite !== b.isFavorite) {
    return a.isFavorite ? -1 : 1;
  } else {
    return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
  
console.log(sortedData);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Try this one:

```js
const data = [
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'B'}, 
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'A'}, 
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'C'}, 
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'D'},
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'A'},
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'A'},
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'D'},
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'Z'},
];

const compareLoc = (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
const result = [...data.filter(d => d.isFavorite).sort(compareLoc),
...data.filter(d => !d.isFavorite).sort(compareLoc)];
console.log(result);
```

Following snippet works.

```js
const data = [
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'B'}, 
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'A'}, 
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'C'}, 
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'D'},
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'A'},
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'A'},
  {isFavorite: false, name: 'D'},
  {isFavorite: true, name: 'Z'},
];

data.sort(function (x, y) {
    // if both are true or false, we should compare name attributes
    if (x.isFavorite === y.isFavorite) {
        return x.name.localeCompare(y.name);
    } return x.isFavorite ? -1 : 1
}
)
console.log(data)
```

Comment: This almost works for me, the strange thing is that everything works fine except at the bottom of my dropdown (array), I have a few items that didn't get sorted like this: a-z, a, c, f, g , w => so the first part is perfectly fine, but after Z comes like 10 items that starts again from "a"

Comment: That's not weird, he doesn't sort the end of the array. You're supposed to sort every case of a condition, and he only does it in the if statement. Copy/paste the code of the if in the else, and below it, and it should work

Comment: Can you post the snippet for clarification? I did what I think you meant but doesn't work

Comment: I didn't get the exact point, don't you need isFavorite(a-z) then !isFavorite(a-z)? Why a-z comes after a-z is I order isFavorite = true ones before false ones in all scenarios

Comment: Exactly, en your snippet does that only at the tail of my array there are a few 'exceptions' : isFavorite(a-z) (works), !isFavorite(a-z) works partly, at the tail I have some items that aren't sorted

Comment: can you share a sample please

Comment: data = [{"a", true}, { "b", true}, {"a", false}, {"g", false}, {"k", false}, {"z", false}, {"b", false}, {"g", false}, {"z", false}]

Comment: It' s like it split in 2 different arrays (this was a shortversion because the real one is much longer

Comment: can you check the upper snippet I just shared

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that **first two `if`'s are overlapping** and second `if` is not reachable if `x.isFavorite` is `true` then first `if` will `return`.

Also, you are not checking some scenarios like `y.isFavorite` is `true` and `x.isFavorite` is not.

You can write it as

```
if ( x.isFavorite != y.isFavorite )
{
   return x.isFavorite ? -1 : 1;
}
else
{
   return x.name.localeCompare( y.name );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :)

```js
var arr = [
  {
    isFavorite: false,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    isFavorite: true,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    isFavorite: true,
    name: 'c'
  },
  {
    isFavorite: false,
    name: 'c'
  }
];

arr.sort(function (x,y) {
    if (x.isFavorite > y.isFavorite){
        return -1;
    }else if(x.isFavorite == y.isFavorite){
        return x.name > y.name;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
});

console.log(arr);
```