# Sorting different arrays in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to sort some parameter in my  typescript model. My model is as follows.

```
export class DataModel {
   ID: String
   point1: Point
   point2 : Point
   point3: Point
   AnotherPoint1: AnotherPoint[]
   AnotherPoint2: AnotherPoint[]
   AnotherPoint3: AnotherPoint[]
}

export class Point {
 Name: String
 Timestamp: String
}

export class AnotherPoint {
 Name: String
 Timestamp: String
}
```

I have sorting logic in my component which take this above Data Model and sorts point as follows:

```
     private sortByNameAndID(dataModel: DataModel[]): DataModel[] {
        return dataModel.sort(function (a, b) {
          const pointA = a.point1.Name.toLowerCase();
          const pointB = b.point1.Name.toLowerCase();
          if (pointA === pointB) {
            const timeA = a.point1.Timestamp;
            const timeB = b.point1.Timestamp;
  return Service.compareDate(new Date(timeA), new Date(timeB));  //here again comparing dates
          }
          if (pointA < pointB ) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (pointA > pointB ) {
            return 1;
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Above sorting logic is working fine for Points but now with this I also need to sort AnotherPoint as well. Means I have to sort all Points and AnotherPoints together as above. How can I do that?

Comment: share input and expected output

Comment: What you want is to sort by two field, am I right? Have you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129952/javascript-sort-array-by-two-fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start creating two helper functions, to compare two `Point`s and two arrays of `AnotherPoint`s respectively. I'm assuming that the arrays are to be compared element by element, stopping as soon as a pair of elements does not compare to 0.

```
function comparePoints(pA: Point | AnotherPoint, pB: Point | AnotherPoint)
{
    const pointA = pA.Name.toLowerCase();
    const pointB = pB.Name.toLowerCase();
    if (pointA < pointB ) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pointA > pointB ) {
        return 1;
    }
    const timeA = pA.Timestamp;
    const timeB = pB.Timestamp;
    return Service.compareDate(new Date(timeA), new Date(timeB));
}

function comparePointArrays(arrayA: AnotherPoint[], arrayB: AnotherPoint[])
{
    const len = Math.min(arrayA.length, arrayB.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        const result = comparePoints(arrayA[i], arrayB[i]);
        if (result !== 0) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then the sorting function can be rewritten using the new helper comparators:

```
private sortByNameAndID(dataModel: DataModel[]): DataModel[] {
    return dataModel.sort(function (a, b) {
        return comparePoints(a.point1, b.point1) ||
            comparePoints(a.point2, b.point2) ||
            comparePoints(a.point3, b.point3) ||
            comparePointArrays(a.AnotherPoint1, b.AnotherPoint1) ||
            comparePointArrays(a.AnotherPoint2, b.AnotherPoint2) ||
            comparePointArrays(a.AnotherPoint3, b.AnotherPoint3);
    });
}
```

Note that the `||` operator only performs the operation on the right if the result of the operation on the left is *falsy* (0), meaning that we will stop comparing points as soon as a comparison reports a nonzero result.

Comment: I think you are missing some basics here: `comparePoints` compares two points. `comparePointArrays` compares _arrays_ of `AnotherPoint`s. It does so by calling `comparePoints` repeatedly on each pair of elements from both arrays. The date comparison is done in `comparePoints` in the very last line. As for the fact that you can't access the functions you may need to put them in the file that contains `sortByNameAndID` but outside the class.

Comment: They are not methods, but helper functions. In TypeScript, you don't need a class to encapsulate any function. As I said, these are absolutely basics, but if you are new to these concepts I'm afraid I won't be able to provide more help without knowing the error message and where it is coming from.