# How do I chain Intl.Collator().compare?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort with two fields, say first name then last name.  How do I chain [Intl.Collator().compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) so I don't have to do something silly like

```
const collator = new Intl.Collator()

const sorted = [...unsorted].sort( (a,b) => {
  const c0 = collator.compare(a.firstName, b.firstName)
  if (c0 === 0) {
    return collator.compare(a.lastName, b.lastName)
  }
  else {
    return c0;
  }
}
```

I am basically looking for an equivalent of [Java's `Comparator.thenComparing()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805606/how-to-sort-by-two-fields-in-java)

This is specifically strings and specifically the `Intl.Collate()` to handle accents so the techniques in [Javascript sort array by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129952/javascript-sort-array-by-two-fields) do not work well or equivalent to the implementation above.

Comment: closing as duplicate since the answer is relatively the same but MOD if you want to open it because it is sufficiently different feel free to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buried deep in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469791/242042 but I adapted it to

```
const sorted = [...unsorted]
  .sort( (a,b) => 
    collator.compare(a.firstName, b.firstName) ||
    collator.compare(a.lastName, b.lastName)
  );
```

relying on the fact that when equal the result is `0` and that translates to `false` which triggers the execution of the result after the `||`