# Sort an array of objects by multiple fields

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects

```
let objs = [
  { name: 'Mark',
    age: 30,
    id: 3,
  },
  { name: 'Anne',
    age: 20,
    id: 2,
  },
  { name: 'James',
    age: 40,
    id: 4,
  },
  { name: 'Jerry',
    age: 30,
    id: 1,
  },
  { name: 'Lucy',
    age: 30,
    id: 5,
  },
  { name: 'Mark',
    age: 30,
    id: 6,
  },
]
```

I have for example an array of fields: ['name', 'age'];
The count of fields is dynamic. It could be 2, 1, or 3.
If it were static, I would use the sort operator | | like this:

```
objs.sort((a,b)=> (a.age - b.age || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: not sure about what you want to achieve, you said you have a second array called fields? what type of data do you have in that other array?

Comment: These are fields to sort by. At first, objects must be sorted by field name. obj1.name > obj2.name, then it should be sorted by age, obj1.age - obj2.age, in a chain. Operator | | does this job, but I don't know the count of fields. It could be sorted only by name field, or by name AND by age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this multi sort function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22672370/3807365 - basically you just tell it which fields to sort by and you shall get a sorting method to pass to your Array.sort.

```js
let objs = [{
    name: 'Mark',
    age: 31,
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    name: 'Anne',
    age: 20,
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    age: 40,
    id: 4,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jerry',
    age: 30,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Lucy',
    age: 30,
    id: 5,
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    age: 30,
    id: 6,
  },
]


function getSortMethod() {
  var _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function(a, b) {
    for (var x in _args) {
      var ax = a[_args[x].substring(1)];
      var bx = b[_args[x].substring(1)];
      var cx;

      ax = typeof ax == "string" ? ax.toLowerCase() : ax / 1;
      bx = typeof bx == "string" ? bx.toLowerCase() : bx / 1;

      if (_args[x].substring(0, 1) == "-") {
        cx = ax;
        ax = bx;
        bx = cx;
      }
      if (ax != bx) {
        return ax < bx ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

objs.sort(getSortMethod('+name', '+age'));
console.log(objs)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```