# Arrange array according to object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Morning!

I made the function in order to organize the array according to the property that the user passes by parameter. But don't run, why?

I want sort by some parameter that exists in the object, like ordering by "wheel" or "id", for example.

```js
const data = [
    {
         "color": "Blue",
         "door": 3,
         "wheel": 3,
         "year": 2005,
         "brand": "GMC",
         "sold": false,
         "owner": "Chalmers Boobyer",
         "motor": 1.7,
         "assembled": "09/08/2022"
     },
     {
         "color": "Indigo",
         "door": 4,
         "wheel": 4,
         "year": 1996,
         "brand": "Lincoln",
         "sold": true,
         "owner": "Morten Coffin",
         "motor": 1.7,
         "assembled": "26/08/2021"
     }
];


function bubbleSort(arr, ord='asc', property){
    if(ord === 'asc'){
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                if(arr[j].property > arr[j+1].property){
                    let temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if(ord === 'desc'){
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                if(arr[j].property < arr[j+1].property){
                    let temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (arr);
}

console.log(bubbleSort(data));
```

Comment: When I ran this in JSFiddle, there was an error; have you addressed that?

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'property')".

Comment: But if I put some property, like 'wheel':  function bubbleSort(arr, ord='asc', property='wheel'). The same error happens

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613340/3807365) is for sorting by arbitrary properties (also multiple(!))

Comment: It's not complaining about `property` itself; it's complaining about property's supposed parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you're accessing the index `j + 1`, you should loop up to `arr.length - 1`.
- Use bracket notation to access properties dynamically.

```js
const data = [
    {
         "color": "Blue",
         "door": 3,
         "wheel": 3,
         "year": 2005,
         "brand": "GMC",
         "sold": false,
         "owner": "Chalmers Boobyer",
         "motor": 1.7,
         "assembled": "09/08/2022"
     },
     {
         "color": "Indigo",
         "door": 4,
         "wheel": 4,
         "year": 1996,
         "brand": "Lincoln",
         "sold": true,
         "owner": "Morten Coffin",
         "motor": 1.7,
         "assembled": "26/08/2021"
     }
];


function bubbleSort(arr, ord='asc', property){
    if(ord === 'asc'){
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++){
                if(arr[j][property] > arr[j+1][property]){
                    let temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if(ord === 'desc'){
        for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++){
                if(arr[j][property] < arr[j+1][property]){
                    let temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return (arr);
}

console.log(bubbleSort(data, 'desc', 'door'));
```

Comment: ty man! works! but why I have to use arr.length - 1 ?

Comment: @EduardoS Because you're using the index `j + 1`.

Comment: understand! ty so much!