# Sorting multi dimensional array by 2 columns - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2 dimensional array with different elements in it. I want to sort the array based on 2 different criteria. One being a string and the other an integer.
Here is an example.

```
var arr = [
    ['ABC', 87, 'WHAT'], 
    ['ABC', 34, 'ARE'], 
    ['DEF', 13, 'YOU'], 
    ['ABC', 18, 'DOING'], 
    ['ABC', 34, 'DOING'],
    ['DEF', 24, 'TODAY']
];
```

I want to sort first by the first element and then by the second element.

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript, how do you sort an array on multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/javascript-how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Sort Multidimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993302/javascript-sort-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward:

If the strings are equal, then break the tie by comparing the integer values, else return the result of `localeCompare`

```
var arr = [
  ['ABC', 87, 'WHAT'],
  ['ABC', 34, 'ARE'],
  ['DEF', 13, 'YOU'],
  ['ABC', 18, 'DOING'],
  ['ABC', 34, 'DOING'],
  ['DEF', 24, 'TODAY'],
  ['ABA', 18, 'TODAY'],
  ['ABA', 11, 'TODAY']
];

function doSort(ascending) {
    ascending = typeof ascending == 'undefined' || ascending == true;
    return function(a, b) {
       var ret = a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) || a[1] - b[1];
       return ascending ? ret : -ret;
    };
}

// sort ascending
arr.sort(doSort());
// sort descending
arr.sort(doSort(false));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jdk06yny/2/)

Comment: Is there no other way to solve this without using the JSON stringify? My program doesn't use JSON

Comment: @DiD `JSON.stringify` is only being used to display the sorted output, you can ignore it. The `doSort` function and `arr.sort(doSort());` call are all you really need.

Comment: @DiD I made it a little easier for you. The only code you need is now all the code that is in the answer. But you can still check out the demo by clicking the link titled Fiddle.