# How to sort multidimensional array by two columns two different directions?

Tags: javascript

Here is my array:

```
var arr = [
  ['ABC', '01/01/2016', '000000001'],
  ['ABC', '02/01/2016', '000000002'],
  ['ABC', '03/01/2016', '000000003'],
  ['DEF', '01/01/2016', '000000004'],
  ['DEF', '02/01/2016', '000000005'],
  ['DEF', '03/01/2016', '000000006'],  
];
```

First I want to sort it by second column DESC and then by first column ASC to get this:

```
var arr = [
  ['ABC', '03/01/2016', '000000003'],
  ['DEF', '03/01/2016', '000000006'],  
  ['ABC', '02/01/2016', '000000002'],
  ['DEF', '02/01/2016', '000000005'],
  ['ABC', '01/01/2016', '000000001'],
  ['DEF', '01/01/2016', '000000004'],
];
```

Is that possible? I found here only examples that allow to sort one direction. The third column can be a combination of first and second (if that helps to sort)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993302/javascript-sort-multidimensional-array

Comment: What have you tried? What code did you write? And last of all what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you Snowmonkey... It works